# How to resize an OpenCV Image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I am using **OpenCV** in python and I am trying to train a cascade. As a beginner, I wanted some practice in creating cascades, and my cascade is going to detect a rubber.

Here I have a simple positive image, with dimension **665*851** pixels.
[image: This is the rubber image]

To make it easier to train, I want to scale the image down to **50*50** pixels. I tried running this simple code in my python shell:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('img.jpg')

resized_img = cv.resize(img, (50,50))

cv.imwrite('img1.jpg', img)
```

This is a lightweight, simple code. My file, `img.jpg` is located in the same directory as this python file. The new file does save, however, the size does not change for some reason.

[image]

Please tell me if there is something wrong with my code...

Thanks.

Comment: you're saving the wrong image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving your original image, `img`, instead of `resized_img`.

Change
`cv.imwrite('img1.jpg', img)`
to
`cv.imwrite('img1.jpg', resized_img)`
and your code should work.

Comment: @Burntlce sorry I am dumb.